# Background Video Zooms

Tags: css, video, background

Trying to create background video in HTML5. The following code unwantedly zooms the display.

CSS:

```
#bgvid3 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I've done extensive testing and estimate the zoom to be between 10%-20%. Trust me, I've allowed for aspect ratio, but still don't understand why it's increasing the scale of the video.

Obviously this is undermining the overall quality of the video, making it appear more pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer...

```
.bgvid3 {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Not sure why this works, but it does (you'd think with width & height 100% you'd have some aspect issues). No zooming and works on all screens.

Comment: You can also add this code for IE.

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
 /* IE only */
 #bgvid2 {
  position:absolute;
  top: 20%;
     left: 50%;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100vh;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
 }
}